# Checkbox in Kendo Grid - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to add checkbox in my kendo grid. But when i use this code, it messed up my grid. My CRUD function didn't work at all and the checkbox is failed to be display too.
This checkbox will be used to inserted the checked data into another table. In this code, i just want to make the checkbox appear without messing up my another function first. Please help me to solve this problem first. Thank you.

This code work well when i using firefox, but when i open this in chrome, the checkbox dissapear

View

```
<div class="tables">
    <div class="table-responsive bs-example widget-shadow">
        <h4>Data Kuisioner:</h4>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<admission.Models.KuisionerPreviewModel>().Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= id_pertanyaan ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />")
            .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='masterCheckBox' onclick='checkAll(this)'/>").Width(80);
            columns.Bound(p => p.id_pertanyaan).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.pertanyaan).Title("Pertanyaan");
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").Sync("sync_handler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id_pertanyaan))
            .Create(update => update.Action("kuisioner_Create", "Kuisioner"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("kuisioner_Update", "Kuisioner"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("kuisioner_read", "Kuisioner"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("kuisioner_Delete", "Kuisioner"))
        )
    )
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {    
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function() {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });        
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    function sync_handler(e) {
        this.read();
    }
$(function () {
    $('#grid').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#grids').data().kendoGrid;
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        dataItem.set('id_pertanyaan', checked);
    })
})    
        function checkAll(ele) {
    var state = $(ele).is(':checked');
    var grid = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
    $.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function () {
        if (this['id_pertanyaan'] != state)
            this.dirty = true;
        this['id_pertanyaan'] = state;
    });
    grid.refresh();
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: clientTemplate make an error, i don't know if that cause by the js or other @jebar8

Comment: try without client template and confirm the error is caused by client template. Please post the error.

Comment: Column 'IsChecked' is not bound in kendo columns

Comment: yeah i had change it, this code works well in firefox, but when i open in chrome, the checkbox dissapear @Vijai

Comment: Use browser developer tool F12 and analyze the difference in FF and Chrome